# Overriding libraries shipped with groovy in groovsh?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Groovy ships various third party libraries. The servlet-api (v2.4) is an example for groovy (v 2.0.1):

```
groovy:000> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.protectionDomain.codeSource
===> (file:/usr/lib/groovy/2.0.1/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar <no signer certificates>)
groovy:000>
```

Assuming I want a more recent version: What is the suggested approach to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem when I was using a Groovy script to run an embedded instance of Jetty 9.1.x. After a lot of class loading contortions the only thing that worked was to specify the JAR on the command line using `-cp` option:

```
groovysh -cp javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
```

This places the URL of the JAR in front of the included servlet-api so that it's checked first. Doesn't seem like there's another way around it for now:

```
groovy:000> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.protectionDomain.codeSource
===> (file:/<current directory>/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar <no signer certificates>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the old from `groovy/lib/` and added the one i wanted in `/home/will/.groovy/lib/` I think you could also add directly to the original lib dir

Comment: I have to say I hate the answer. :) Unfortunately there seems to be no straight forward programmatical solution to get this kind of jar "out of the way".

Comment: Hahaha! Aw! It probably has a better way around, i don't know a lot about groovy classpath's. You could try printing it's classpath to see if you can get something: `println System.properties`

Comment: Been there, done that. Did neither find a way to remove resources from the classloader, nor did I find a "ready-to-use" classloader looking locally first (to avoid resources being resolved by the parent cl).